# Data Lakes Tab in Visual Studio Missing?

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-data-lake

- I've downloaded and installed each [Data Lakes MSI](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49504)
- I've created a console application and [installed the required packages](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/data-lake-analytics-get-started-net-sdk/)
- I also HAVE ACCESS to Data Lakes in Azure (though I wont show you that)

Am I missing something?

**DOOD, WHERE'S MY TAB?**
[image]

**IT SHOULD APPEAR LIKE THIS...RIGHT?**
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry for the confusion here - but we have changed the behavior that the "Data Lake" menu is hided by default. You can show it again by creating a U-SQL project (or visiting any Data lake realted activities).

The reason behind that is we are now releasing Data Lake Tools for VS together with Azure SDK (which is a central package for developing Azure related services) and in order to avoid disturbing users, we have hided that menu.

Hope this helps, and feel free to let me know if you have more questions.

Thanks

Xiaoyong Zhu from Azure Data Lake

Comment: I have never created an Azure Data Lake project, but the menu item is present in my VS2015 installation. How can I hide it?

Comment: In the latest update, we have hided it by default (unless you have created a new U-SQL project). You can get the latest update from the location here: http://aka.ms/adltoolsvs

Comment: There is a bug in the Data Lake extension: if you open VS2015.U3 and press "Ctrl+(Comma)" and type into the search box, the search box will disappear after 1 keystroke and the Azure Data Lake menu will appear. A 2x2px white square also appears on my monitor in the top-left corner. Spy++ shows that VS owns that 2x2px window.

Comment: @Dai sorry for the response, but I asked our tester to try it out in our test environments and didn't find this:(  Are you still seeing the same issue now?

Comment: Yes, I still see the behaviour in VS15U3. I removed the Azure Data Lake extension via Add/Remove Programs and it's fine now. What is your MS alias? I can ping you on Skype-for-Business.

Comment: You can reach me at xiaoyzhu at microsoft dot com.